# Powershell - NewScheduledTaskTrigger for last Tuesday of every month

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

Not sure if this belongs in stackoverflow as it relates to PowerShell, but posted here as it isn't scripting and is more server task related.

I am trying to recreate a task we have on our old file server, as a Clustered task on our new failover cluster.

In order to do so, I need to set the action and trigger, as variables to pass to New-ClusteredScheduledTask. The action I have done without issue, but I am not sure how to run New-ScheduledTaskTrigger to correctly have it set to the last Tuesday of every month.

I can see there are Daily and Weekly switches, and also WeeklyInterval, but I don't want to rely on weekly intervals as that won't always fall on the last Tuesday of the month?

Can anyone advise how to recreate this trigger using a combination of the available switches and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think this can be done purely with PowerShell cmdlets.

I would create a sample task in the GUI with the correct trigger and export it as XML.

Then use that XML to create a new task: `Register-ScheduledTask -Xml`

Comment: Can this be done as a clustered scheduled task though?

Comment: Sorry, messed up the pasting of the link to the MS documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-clusteredscheduledtask?view=win10-ps

Comment: It doesn't actually seem to work as expected though, as I have exported a task from our old file server, and then tried to register as a clustered scheduled task on the new cluster, and all I get is "Register-ClusteredScheduledTask: The task XML is malformed". Odd, considering I haven't even edited it. I also tried export an existing clustered task and importing it, but that also fails?

Comment: Ok, turns out it's because I was passing the path to the XML file as the value for -Xml. After doing a get-contents I was able to pass the entire XML as a string to that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do something similar in the past; and I never found a way to do it using New-ScheduledTaskTrigger.

Ultimately I ended up adding the logic to do that check to my script so it only runs if there are less than 7 days left in the month and the current day is Tuesday.

```
If(((([datetime]::DaysInMonth((Get-Date).Year,(Get-Date).Month) - (Get-Date).Day)) -le 7) -And ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq "Tuesday"))
{
   # Perform Task
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good suggestion. Does seem odd that Microsoft have not added the ability to do this to the PowerShell commandlets

Comment: Am going to accept Peter's answer, purely because it is closer to what I would consider a "native" way of achieving the desired triggers.